# Why was this 'too chatty' comment flag declined?

Tags: support, comments, flagging

I happened to come across this answer: [Add a randomised body class](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/11647/add-a-randomised-body-class/11649#11649). I noticed that it had a [comment](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/11647/add-a-randomised-body-class/11649#comment13763_11649) that said, simply,

> This looks perfect, thanks!

So I flagged this as 'too chatty'.

When you go to post a comment, you see this:

[image: see blockquote below]

> Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. **Avoid comments like "+1" or "thanks".

And [Jeff Atwood said to flag these](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/15292/294691).

And yet, my flag was declined:

[image: too chatty – Mithrandir Jun 12 at 9:54 declined]

So... why? Is there some sort of misunderstanding here?

Comment: With the new flags, it could be flagged as *it's no longer needed*: This comment is outdated,**conversational** or not relevant to this post..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's me. Sorry for any frustration! I just disagree with the idea that these comments need to be scrupulously policed. They're courteous and don't get in the way in a substantial way. If someone is carrying on a multi-reply conversation in comments, then sure, too chatty.

I understand, though, that Jeff's official stance is different. I just think within reason, a "thanks" and/or a "you're welcome" isn't hurting anyone. For what it's worth, others have expressed similar viewpoint on Stack Overflow Meta and other Metas.

That said, if you feel strongly please re-flag and I will not decline it this time!

I would be curious to hear other users of this site chime in with how they feel "thank you" and "you're welcome" comments should be treated.

Comment: It's not a big deal, I just dislike having flags declined :). I guess I can just leave them here if you don't think they're a problem; I was just wondering if perhaps there was a misunderstanding.